# filter array of object based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

#### tl;dr

Im trying to deduplicate an array of objects that are not necessarily identical.

#### desc.

i have downloaded a set of records from a site that manages them poorly and there are many duplicates of records, though some with different names or different weights. What id like to do is compare each record to each other record and remove all entries but the one with the greatest weight, or all but one entry in the case that there is an exact duplicate (including name).

#### Arr obj

```
{
      "entry"   : "Single Lift",
      "name"    : "Jane Doe",
      "sex"     : "female",
      "division": "40-44",
      "equipped": "raw",
      "wtclass" : 66,
      "lift"    : "bench press",
      "weight"  : 151
  }
```

#### Pseudo

```
function dedupe(lift=records){
    console.log(lift.length)
    lift.forEach((record,index)=>{
      for(i=0;i<lift.length;i++){
        if(record.sex===lift[i].sex){
          if(record.division===lift[i].division){
            if(record.equipped===lift[i].equipped){
              if(record.wtclass===lift[i].wtclass){
                if(record.entry===lift[i].entry){
                  if(record.name===lift[i].name&&record.weight===lift[i].weight) lift.splice(i,1)
                  else if(record.weight>lift[i].weight) lift.splice(i,1)
                  else if(record.weight<lift[i].weight) lift.splice(index,1)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    console.log(lift.length)
    return lift
  }
```

This code obviously doesn't operate the way i want it to, but it illustrates the intent. I would like to remove all but the greatest weight (or all but one where all key:values are identical) by comparing the weight on any entry where `entry` `sex` `division` `equipped` `wtclass` and `lift` are a match.

There are other questions around about deduplicating arrays of objects, but i could not find anything that matched my scenario or that i could adapt to work for me. If anyone has a solution (or a link to a solution) i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Best you can do is declare an empty array. Then loop over the data you have and push the objects if they are not already present in the empty array. If they are present, check if the weight is bigger and replace it. And so on. Forget this IF hell you wrote

Comment: I'm a little unclear, are you saying you want to find all the personal bests for each duplicate of 'everything but weight'?  Because yBrodsky's comment would be correct if so.

Comment: My issue is that some lifts have been entered twice as exact duplicates (not hard to deal with) but also when a record was broken, sometimes the old record was not removed, so there will be two of the same record with different weight values. I only want to keep a given record with the greatest weight. I am working on a new function based on yBrodsky's suggestion now, but am also interested in the reduce option answered below, though im unfamiliar with reduce

Comment: Ele's answer is using the `reduce` function to build such a new array as yBrodsky mentioned.  It's building a single object with properties called 'Single Lift||Jane Doe||...' (but ignoring the weight).  It will evaluate every element of the original list and decide whether to reassign a duplicate or discard it.  It's the `Object.values()` part that converts the object of properties to an array.  The only reason it would fail as it is, is if the object data you pass it has property names in a different order, or sometimes more properties than their duplicates. (I doubt that is likely).

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski updated!

Comment: A quick copy paste of Ele's code definitely gets it done, though i dont understand what its doing very well. Thats fine by me though, t least i have something that works, and can start googling to understand what im seeing! thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @Ele ...wow.  That's actually more beautiful, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With those values you can concatenate them and check for the duplicates.

You can use the function `reduce`.

*This example has two objects with the same values (but the weights) and one of them with different values.*

```js
var array = [
  {
    'entry': 'Single Lift',
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'g': 'f',
    'division': '40-44',
    'equipped': 'raw',
    'wtclass': 66,
    'lift':
    'bench press', 'weight': 151
  },
  {
    'entry': 'Single Lift',
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'g': 'f',
    'division': '40-44',
    'equipped': 'raw',
    'wtclass': 66,
    'lift': 'bench press',
    'weight': 160
  },
  {
    'entry': 'Single Lift', 
    'name': 'Ele', 
    'g': 'm', 
    'division': '40-44', 
    'equipped': 'raw', 
    'wtclass': 66, 
    'lift': 'bench press', 
    'weight': 151
  }
]

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, o) => {
  var {
    entry, 
    name, 
    g, 
    division, 
    equipped, 
    wtclass, lift
  } = o
  
  var key = [
    entry, 
    name, 
    g, 
    division, 
    equipped, 
    wtclass, 
    lift
  ].join('||')

  if (!a[key] || o.weight > a[key].weight) {
    a[key] = o
  }

  return a
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { "entry"   : "Single Lift", "name"    : "Jane Doe", "sex"     : "female", "division": "40-44", "equipped": "raw", "wtclass" : 66, "lift"    : "bench press", "weight"  : 151 }, { "entry"   : "Single Lift", "name"    : "Jane Doe", "sex"     : "female", "division": "40-44", "equipped": "raw", "wtclass" : 66, "lift"    : "bench press", "weight"  : 152 }, { "entry"   : "Single Lift", "name"    : "Jane Doe", "sex"     : "female", "division": "40-44", "equipped": "raw", "wtclass" : 66, "lift"    : "bench press", "weight"  : 151 }, { "entry"   : "Double Lift", "name"    : "Jane Doe", "sex"     : "female", "division": "40-44", "equipped": "raw", "wtclass" : 66, "lift"    : "bench press", "weight"  : 151 }
]

const groupBy = (xs, exceptions) => 
   xs.reduce((groups, element) => {
     var key = Object.assign({}, element);
     for (let i = 0; i < exceptions.length; i++) {
       delete key[exceptions[i]];
     }
     key = Object.values(key).join(',');
           
     if (!groups[key]) {
        groups[key] = [element];
     } else {
        groups[key].push(element);
     }

     return groups;
   }, {})

let grouppedRecords = groupBy(array, ['weight']);

let biggestWeightRecords = Object.values(grouppedRecords).map(records => {
  let biggestWeightRecord = records[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    if (records[i].weight > biggestWeightRecord.weight) {
      biggestWeightRecord = records[i];
    }
  }
  return biggestWeightRecord;
});

console.log(biggestWeightRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with 2 iterations, admit any number of properties to filter by, two rules (bigger and smaller), just works if the values of filter properties are primitive values.

```
const elements = [
    {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        fooBard: 3,
    },
    {
        foo: 2,
        bar: 2,
        fooBard: 6,
    },
    {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        fooBard: 5,
    },
    {
        foo: 2,
        bar: 2,
        fooBard: 3,
    }
];

const RULE_BIGGER = 'RULE_BIGGER';
const RULE_SMALLER = 'RULE_SMALLER';

const elementsFiltered = new Map();

const createKey = (element, ...matchingProperties) =>
    matchingProperties
    .map(matchProperty => element[matchProperty] || '')
    .join('#');


const hasToBeUpdated = (rule) => (oldValue, newValue) => {
    switch (rule) {
        case RULE_BIGGER:
            return newValue > oldValue;
        case RULE_SMALLER:
            return newValue < oldValue;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

const filterByProperty = (elements, property, rule, ...matchingProperties) => {
    const hasToBeUpdatedWithRule = hasToBeUpdated(rule);
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        const key = createKey(element, ...matchingProperties);
        const storedElement = elementsFiltered.get(key)
        if (!storedElement ||
            hasToBeUpdatedWithRule(storedElement[property], element[property])) {
                elementsFiltered.set(key, element);
        }
    });
    const result = [];
    elementsFiltered.forEach(elementFiltered => {
        result.push(elementFiltered);
    });
    return result;
};

const result = filterByProperty(elements, 'fooBard', RULE_BIGGER, 'foo', 'bar');

console.log(result);
```